# Password of the oracle user in oracle linux?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I am trying to install oracle 12c on my virtualbox oracle linux 6.5. I ran the command `oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall` , which created a user oracle . But I can't seem to login to the user cause I don't know the password. What is the password ?

Comment: Become the root user ("su -") and then issue the command "passwd oracle" - you will be prompted for a new password.

Comment: This should be the right answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall` package includes a bash script that creates the oracle user, if not already existing, using the `useradd` command.

In this case in log file `/var/log/oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall/results/orakernel.log` you should see this entry:

> Please set password for oracle user

You can run the following command as root to assign a password:

```
# passwd oracle
```